# Border transition on click without javascript

Tags: html, css

My issue is I need to add a transition of 5sec on the border of a button when we click it without javascript.
Can anyone suggest me an idea

Comment: you can use [active-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

Comment: Add the HTML you need that on.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> [:active](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

```css
.btn{
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding:10px;
  border:0;
  border-radius:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: border 5s;
}

.btn:active{
  border:solid blue 5px
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: You could also potentially use `focus` depending on whether you want to click and hold or not (Though obviously focus comes with it's own caveats, e.g. you would trigger the effect if you tabbed through to the element)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by transition, or by an animation.
Note that there is no CSS selector like `button:click{}`, so you have to use the `:active` css selector, wich has the downside, that you have to hold your click for (in your case) 5s to make the animation work.

If you want an animation on "click" you WILL have to use javascript, I dont think there is any method that uses pure CSS to to the trick here.

```css
#b1 {
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition: border 5s;
}

#b1:active {
  border: 5px solid green;

}

#b2{
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#b2:active{
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: border_transition;
}

@keyframes border_transition {
  0% {
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
  100% {
    border: 5px solid green;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="b1">CLICK ME</button>
<button id="b2">CLICK ME2</button>
```